# Strange behavior of switch function in R

Tags: r

I have a strange problem of switch function in R.

The code is very simple ,but I do not understand the behavior.

Example:OK

```
a=1

switch(a,             
       "1" = print("one"),   
       "2" = print("two"),  
       print("?")            
        )
```

1. Correct
   a=1 >>> `[1] "one"`
2. Correct
   a=2 >>> `[1] "two"`
3. Corrct
   a=3 >>> `[1] "?"`

**4) Strange**
a=0 >>> Nothing printed.
a=-1 >>> Nothing printed.

Another example is also strange

```
a=-1

switch(a,             
       "1" = print("one"),   
       "-1" = print("minus"),  
       print("?")            
        )
```

Nothing printed!

Why the case of minus value causes the unexpected behavior?

Comment: `switch(as.character(a), ...)` Read the documentation of the function `switch()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should force the value of a to a character before comparing it. It seems not to process negative integers as expected. But with `as.character()` it works just fine.

```
a=-1

switch(as.character(a),             
       "1" = print("one"),   
       "-1" = print("minus"),  
       print("?")            
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. It is clear for me.